# It is possible to use a batch file to read a line and then use only a substring of that line to perform a command?

Tags: batch-file, substring, xcopy

I am working with ClearCase and I would like to use a batch script to run through a text file generated through cleartool commands, copy a file specified in the line, but then perform a rename by only extracting a substring up until a specified set of characters.

An example text file is:

```
"M:\LEVEL1\PROJECT\src\ROOT\file 2.txt@@\main\LEVEL1\5"
"M:\LEVEL1\PROJECT\src\ROOT\file 1.txt@@\main\LEVEL1\3"
"M:\LEVEL1\PROJECT\src\ROOT\folder 1\file 5.txt@@\main\LEVEL1\2"
"M:\LEVEL1\PROJECT\src\ROOT\file 4.txt@@\main\LEVEL1\3"
"M:\LEVEL1\PROJECT\src\ROOT\file 7.txt@@\main\LEVEL1\2"
```

What I would like to do is create a command that looks like this (using the first line):

```
xcopy "M:\LEVEL1\PROJECT\src\ROOT\file 2.txt@@\main\LEVEL1\5" "<output folder>\LEVEL1\PROJECT\src\ROOT\file 2.txt"
```

where `<output folder>` is a folder that is specified as a parameter when running the script.  So basically what I am asking for is to extract only what lies between `M:` and `@@` in each line as it is read so I can use it in a copy command.

I already have `xcopy "%%~fA" "%OUTPUTDIR:"=%\%%~pnxA"` which copies a line to an output directory but the `%%~pnxA` will only remove the drive letter and not remove the remaining part of the line from `@@` onwards.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried something like this?

`for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:@" %%A in (in.txt) do echo xcopy %%A:%%B@@%%C DIR:%%B`

Comment: MAGIC! thank you so much, this is brilliant! no idea how the logic works.

Answer (score 2):

Just breaking up JJRythms answer into an explanation.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:@" %%A in (in.txt) do xcopy %%A:%%B@@%%C DIR:%%B
```

The purpose of this statement is to parse the lines in the `in.txt` file and then use the pieces we want.

- [`for`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) - the loop command.
- [`/F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) - the File parsing loop type option.
- `tokens=1,2,3` - the sub-strings in which to retrieve based upon the string delimiters.
- `delims=:@` - the delimiters which separate the tokens. (Default is spaces)
- `%%A` - the starting loop variable. (Token 1 = `%%A`, Token 2 = `%%B`, Token 3 = `%%C`)
- `in (in.txt)` the file in which to perform the loop command.
- `do` - the commands to perform for each line of the file.

Example Using the first line.

```
"M:\LEVEL1\PROJECT\src\ROOT\file 2.txt@@\main\LEVEL1\5"
```

Is parsed as:

```
%%A = "M
%%B = \LEVEL1\PROJECT\src\ROOT\file 2.txt
%%C = \main\LEVEL1\5"
```

The delimiters are consumed and therefore removed from the resulting variables.

Note that this solution will not work if there are any `@` signs anywhere else in the file name.

Type [`for /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) on the command line for help and options.